# Understanding multiple databases in Heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I recently installed the heroku `dev` [database](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/).  Then when I type into the command line `heroku pg:info` I get THREE databases.

```
=== SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL)
Data Size    808k

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE
Plan         Dev
Status       available
Connections  1
PG Version   9.1.3
Created      2012-05-14 17:47 UTC
Tables       0
Conn Info    "host=XXXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
             port=5432 dbname=resourceXXXXX
             user=abcXXXXX sslmode=require
             password=XXXXXXXXX"

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL
Plan         Dev
Status       available
Connections  1
PG Version   9.1.3
Created      2012-05-13 19:08 UTC
Tables       0
Conn Info    "host=XXXXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
             port=5432 dbname=resourceXXXXX
             user=YYYYYY sslmode=require
             password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN
Plan         Dev
Status       available
Connections  1
PG Version   9.1.3
Created      2012-05-13 19:06 UTC
Tables       0
Conn Info    "host=XXXXXXXXXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
             port=5432 dbname=resourceXXXXXX
             user=XXXXXXXXXX sslmode=require
             password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

The host, resource, user, and password are different for each.

Why are there three?  What's the difference between them?

Comment: Maybe some bug, or you added 3 of them. You are suppose to have only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the dev plan similar to the production plan you are able to add multiple databases. Each of these is a unique database and you can connect to each of them individually.

If you wished to remove a database if you did not intend to add three you could:

```
heroku addons:remove HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN
```

To promote one of those to your primary database you may:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN
```

You may also connect to each of them individually:

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install the add-on multiple times it creates multiple entries.  I deleted the app and readded the addon and now there is only one entry.  I guess previously, I inadvertently added the addon multiple times.